# findViewById returns null when searching for elements in the actionbar on android 3.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am working on an app which uses a custom actionbar layout, which is referenced via `android:actionBarStyle` and `android:customNavigationLayout` in the `themes.xml`.
There are some elements in the bar, like a reload and some info button.
On `android 4` devices those buttons can be found via `findViewById` (inside the activity), but on `android 3.2` `findViewById` returns **null**. This throws a NullPointerException then.

The app is using ActionbarSherlock 4.2.0

Here is the themes.xml:

```
 <style name="Theme.SRF.Tablet" parent="style/Theme.Sherlock">
     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/header_shadow</item>
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TTTActionBar</item> </style>

 <style name="TTTActionBar" parent="style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_header</item>
     <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/actionbar_custom</item>
 </style>
```

Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(...);
        // next line throws NullPointerException on android 3.2
        findViewById(R.id.actionbar_custom_bt_refresh).setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        ....
    }
```

Comment: If you're using a SherlockActivity try `getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(...)` but I don't know why it behaves different on different Android versions.

Comment: getSupportActionBar().getCustomView() returns null :(

Comment: Please provide your `@layout/actionbar_custom`

Comment: have your tried this in `onResume`?  the layout may not have completed yet.  Also aren't you supposed to have 2 names for each theme item?  one prefixed with `android:` and one not

Comment: can u put the zipped code somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont know if this would help you, but from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12964535/1739882):

Try adding:

```
<item name="customNavigationLayout">@layout/custom_action</item>
```

to go along with:

```
<item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/custom_action</item>
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is what I meant from my comment on the question.  Would be a better answer if you clarified as to why that is needed.  +1 though.

Comment: (I think this is because ABS does not use the default AB in 3.1, so items namespaced with `android:` aren't used by ABS)

Answer (score 2):

The views aren't guaranteed to be ready yet in `onCreate`, you'll want to wait until `onCreateView` or even `onActivityCreated` to be safe. Usually `onCreateView` is okay but it's always a good idea to do a null check on the View just in case.

[onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)

> Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in
>   the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like
>   the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point.
>   If you want to do work once the activity itself is created, see
>   onActivityCreated(Bundle).

[onCreateView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

> Called to have the fragment instantiate its user interface view. This
>   is optional, and non-graphical fragments can return null (which is the
>   default implementation). This will be called between onCreate(Bundle)
>   and onActivityCreated(Bundle).
>
> If you return a View from here, you will later be called in
>   onDestroyView() when the view is being released.

[onActivityCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29)

> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this
>   fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final
>   initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving
>   views or restoring state. It is also useful for fragments that use
>   setRetainInstance(boolean) to retain their instance, as this callback
>   tells the fragment when it is fully associated with the new activity
>   instance. This is called after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup,
>   Bundle) and before onViewStateRestored(Bundle).